# Is there any way to easily give an SVG an inset box shadow?

Tags: html, css, shadow, dropshadow

I'd like to be able to add a subtle inset shadow to this house shaped SVG.

```css
* {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  text-align: center;
}

.homeButton {
  fill: white;
  margin-top: 12em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg class="homeButton" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="10em" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1h-32l.7 160.2c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1V472c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40H456c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1H416 392c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40V448 384c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32H256c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v64 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40H160 128.1c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2H104c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40V360c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8V287.6H32c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z"/></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried copy pasting code from the internet, which was all I could do as I have very limited experience with this sort of thing. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filter is not an inset directly into the svg, consider using a custom filter tag:

```
<svg class="homeButton" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="10em" viewBox="0 0 576 512" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1">
        <filter id="inset-shadow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feComponentTransfer in=SourceAlpha>
                <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="40" />
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="50" result="offsetblur" />
            <feFlood flood-color="rgb(20, 0, 0)" result="color" />
            <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in" />
            <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
                <feMergeNode />
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <path filter="url(#inset-shadow)"
            d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1h-32l.7 160.2c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1V472c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40H456c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1H416 392c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40V448 384c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32H256c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v64 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40H160 128.1c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2H104c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40V360c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8V287.6H32c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z" />
```

Comment: No problems! Could you mark me as the answer and upvote?

Comment: I marked your post as the answer, but as I'm new here I don't have a high enough reputation to upvote it, lol. Sorry 

Comment: Haha! Don't worry about it man, I'm still happy to help 